# Spring Data JPA - exception when using findAll with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity, and the DAO with interface `JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>`. Using EclipseLink.

I'm using the following method from the DAO:

```
Iterable<MyEntity> findAll(Iterable<Long> ids);
```

in this way:

```
List<Long> listOfIds = Arrays.asList(new Long[] {1,2,3});
Iterable<MyEntity> entities = dao.findAll(listOfIds);
```

I've got the MySQL exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

The SQL query that is executed in the database has the following syntax:

```
SELECT id, creation_date, column1, column2 FROM my_entity WHERE (id IN ((1,2,3)))
```

The problem is in the last braces - there are too many of them. The working query is:

```
SELECT id, creation_date, column1, column2 FROM my_entity WHERE (id IN (1,2,3))
```

Any reason why the Spring Data adds these unnecessary braces? Any way to fix it?

Comment: Please post `MyEntity` class code + the declaration of `listOfIds`

Comment: Provided example declaration of `listOfIds` in edit. The entity is a POJO annotated with `@Entity`.

Comment: Which OR mapper do you use?

Comment: @MatthiasHerlitzius sorry but I don't know what you are asking about

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: Then your problem might be related to a bug. See this link and further links to bug reports at the end: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/119934-in-clause-not-working-for-jpa-eclipselink-repository-mysql-error

Comment: Seems to be the same problem. I did not find this, thanks for the link.

Comment: This guy found an answer. Hi is my hero https://stackoverflow.com/a/30779058/268764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FOUND WORKAROUND**

First of all, your DAO must also implement the `JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity>`.
Then, create a Specification-factory class like this:

```
public final class MyEntitySpecifications {
    public static Specification<MyEntity> idsIn(final Collection<Long> ids) {
        return new Specification<MyEntity>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return root.get("id").in(ids);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and use your DAO like this:

```
Iterable<MyEntity> entities = dao.findAll(MyEntitySpecifications.idsIn(listOfIds));
```

Produced query is now as expected.