# Why does Spring Data JPA + Hibernate generate incorrect SQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship. I want to get all entities
that are tied to a set of the other entity. This are my classes:

```
public class Instance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instance")
    private Set<Action> actions = new HashSet<>();

}

public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "instance_id")
    private Instance instance;

}
```

Furthermore I have the following repository:

```
public interface InstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Instance, Long> {

    List<Instance> findByActions(Set<Action> actions);

}
```

When I call the method with empty or single element sets, I get no errors. But if the set contains more elements
I get an exception. MySQL says `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. The generated SQL for empty or single element
sets is

```
select instance0_.id as id1_3_
from instance instance0_
left outer join action actions1_
on instance0_.id=actions1_.instance_id
where actions1_.id=?
```

and for other sets

```
select instance0_.id as id1_3_
from instance instance0_
left outer join action actions1_
on instance0_.id=actions1_.instance_id
where actions1_.id=(?, ?, ?, ...)
```

This is obviously wrong and it should be something like

```
select instance0_.id as id1_3_
from instance instance0_
left outer join action actions1_
on instance0_.id=actions1_.instance_id
where actions1_.id in (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

Why does Hibernate generate this SQL and how do I fix it?

Comment: are you 100% certain Spring Data JPA is *supposed* to support collections as a parameter, and that behavior is actually defined?

Comment: Did you try to defining the query yourself using a  @Query("select ...") Tag? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: @Ajan already provided the correct answer. I was missing the `In` at the end of the query method.

Comment: You need to put the suffix `In` for every property for which you plan to pass a collection of values.  See @Ajan's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Spring Data [spec](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) you have to define this method as:

```
List<Instance> findByActionsIn(Collection<Action> actions);
```